# Python to find and replace string within certain lines of file

Tags: python-3.x, regex, scripting, file-handling

I have file

```
Mod top (o i)
In a
Op a
End


Mod mid (o i)
In a
Op a
End

Mod bottom (o i)
In a
Op a
End
```

I want to replace “a” with “z” only in mid.

```
with open(‘data.txt’,'r') as file:
read_lines = file.readlines()
for line in read_lines:
    print line.replace(string_to_be_identified,string_to_be_replace)
file.close()
```

I tried to match using regex and then replace but it will repalce all lines after it but i want only in that “mid”

Expected

```
Mod top (o i)
In a
Op a
End


Mod mid (o i)
In z
Op z
End

Mod bottom (o i)
In a
Op a
End
```

Comment: Could you post expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import re

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    data = f_in.read()

data = re.sub(
    r"(?s)Mod mid.*?End", lambda g: g.group(0).replace(" a", " z"), data
)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
Mod top (o i)
In a
Op a
End


Mod mid (o i)
In z
Op z
End

Mod bottom (o i)
In a
Op a
End
```

Comment: What does lambda g.group(0) mean and r in beginning of re.sub is regexp ??

Comment: @flash `r"string"` means raw-string in Python (prefix that disables most escape sequence processing). `g.group(0)` in `re.sub` means that I want to get the whole matched string (group 0)